# How to get category collection using product id in product details page in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

How can I get a category collection in the product details page? I've tried using the below code, but it's not getting the collection.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')
    ->registry('current_category');
$categoryProducts = $category->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the product detail page you can just call **getCategoryCollection** function on product's Object to get Category Collection as following :

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$categoryCollection = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
```

Comment: You can also add category attributes to the collection - `$_product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))`

Comment: This work's usually, but it does not work when you go directly to a product from the home page. Not through the category page.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, your using $categoryId but it is undefined.

Try:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); 
$categoryProducts = $category ->getCategoryProducts($category->getId());
```